# HTML Option values not being inputted into my controller

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, http

In the following controller method

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index (HttpPostedFileBase file, string selectedOrgName, string selectedCatName)
    {
        PortalData PD = new PortalData();

        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            try
            {

                string[] newFileNamePieces = { selectedOrgName, selectedCatName, Path.GetFileName(file.FileName) };

                string newFileName = string.Join("-", newFileNamePieces); // Creates new file name of the form [organization]-[category]-[file name with extension]

                file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Assets"),newFileName)); // Saves file with new file name in assets folder

                string fileId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", string.Empty); // randomly generated file id (a GUID without any hyphens)
                                                                                      // e.g. 752355644d434751866653da303a40b1     

                ViewBag.Message = string.Format("File {0} ({1}KB) uploaded and saved successfully! File ID: {2}. File should be found at {3}", newFileName, (file.ContentLength / 1024).ToString(), fileId, Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/assets"),newFileName));

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "ERROR:" + ex.Message.ToString();
            }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "You have not specified a file.";
        }

        ViewBag.orgcatJSON = PD.mapOrgs2Cats();

        return View();
    }
```

where `selectedOrgName` and `selectedCatName` are supposed to come from the `<Select>` elements

```
<select class="selectpicker" name="selectedOrgName" id="orglist">
    <!-- houses the Option elements corresponding to organizations -->
    <option value="companyA">companyA</option>
    <option value="companyB">companyB</option
</select>
```

and

```
<select class="selectpicker" name="selectedCatName" id="catlist">
     !-- houses the options elements corresponding to the categories for the organization selected in  #orglist -->
     <option value="somecategory">somecategory</option>
</select>
```

I'm noticing that `selectedOrgName` and `selectedCatName` are empty when my method is invoked. Based upon the code I've posted, is there any glaring reason why this is?

Comment: why don't you use a view model?

Comment: Did you check that those elements are not defined outside the form ? In that case they would be posted as null.

Comment: @Fabian You were right about  that ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue seems to be that the select elements were defined outside the form element (which posts them as null in the Controller):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post)){
     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
}

<select class="selectpicker" name="selectedOrgName" id="orglist">
       <!-- houses the Option elements corresponding to organizations -->
       <option value="companyA">companyA</option>
       <option value="companyB">
        companyB
       </option>
</select>
```

They need to be inside the form to be assigned by MVC as a parameter in the Controller  (**correct version**):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <select class="selectpicker" name="selectedOrgName" id="orglist">
        <!-- houses the Option elements corresponding to organizations -->
        <option value="companyA">companyA</option>
        <option value="companyB">
            companyB
        </option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
}
```